Low beam on one head light doesnt work but high does
2018 Toyota Yaris iA. Noticed one of my headlights was out so I swapped the bulb and nothing. Then noticed high beam worked. Tried old bulb again and high beam worked. So bulb doesn't seem to be issue.  I'm semi car literate but trying to avoid going to mechanic to pay out the nose for what might be a simple issue. Any ideas where to start looking til I get out of my depth and pay a pro? TIA

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

When you say you swapped the bulb, was the replacement a brand new bulb? If it was, have you tried swapping in the bulb from the working side? Trying to rule out the possibility that the new bulb is faulty; I realise this is probably a long shot, but it's probably worth a try.

Yeah it was a brand new bulb. Didn't try swapping bulb from working side
